# Remove elements from tuple array that have same value in first index position of each element

Tags: python, arrays, list

Lets say I have a list:

```
t = [('a', 1), ('a', 6), ('b', 2), ('c', 3),  ('c', 5), ('d', 4)]
```

There are two tuples with 'a' as the first element, and two tuples with 'c' as the first element. I want to only keep the first instance of each, so I end up with:

```
t = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby is worth looking in to

Comment: @gold_cy thanks for the link, looks promising. I don't understand [k for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')] , doesn't groupby need two inputs (data, keyfunc)? The example they gave only provided the data

Comment: >> key defaults to an identity function and returns the element unchanged. Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function. You need to provide a key function on what you need to group by, in this case the first item of each tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to help you filter the duplicate keys:

```
>>> t = [('a', 1), ('a', 6), ('b', 2), ('c', 3),  ('c', 5), ('d', 4)]
>>> d = {}
>>> for x, y in t:
...     if x not in d:
...             d[x] = y
...
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
>>> t = list(d.items())
>>> t
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

@MrGeek's answer is good, but if you do not want to use a dictionary, you could do something simply like this:

```
>>> t = [('a', 1), ('a', 6), ('b', 2), ('c', 3),  ('c', 5), ('d', 4)]
>>> already_seen = []
>>> for e in t:
...     if e[0] not in already_seen:
...         already_seen.append(e[0])
...     else:
...         t.remove(e)
...
>>> t
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```

Comment: modifying an object while iterating over it, not advised, not to mention you alter the original data object

Comment: Unless you want to "clean" that object... he basically wanted to get that new list assigned to the same variable...

Answer (score 0):

@gold_cy's Comment is the easiest way:

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in order to group your data. We use `key` param to group by the first element of each tuple.

```
import itertools as it

t = [list(my_iterator)[0] for g, my_iterator in it.groupby(t, key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

Output:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```